# Show that $X^p-a=(X-\alpha)^p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

I'm referencing [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2368626/637375) here. It says that we have a field $T$ with characteristic $p$ and $a\in T$ such that $a\neq b^p$ $\forall b\in T$

If we look at $f(X)=X^p-a$ and a root $\alpha$ of $f$, then $X^p-a=(X-\alpha)^p$.

I'm curious to why this is. Maybe because $\alpha^p=a$ and then

\begin{align*}
(X-\alpha)^p = X^p+(\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\binom{p}{k} (-\alpha)^kX^{k-1})-\underbrace{\alpha^p}_{a}
\end{align*}
But then what? The middle-term isn't equal to $X^p-a$ in general.

Comment: All middle terms are zero because $p = 0$ in a field of characteristic $p$.

Comment: All binomial coefficients, but the first and the last ones, are divisible by $p$ if $p$ is prime.

Comment: Yes but $\binom{p}{k} = \frac{p!}{k!(p-k)!}$ and $p!=0!=1$

Comment: @Quotenbanane Note that $p \equiv 0$ mod $p$ does not imply $p! \equiv 0! = 1$ mod $p$.

Comment: Ah yes, it's clear now. Thanks to you all for the help.